# Using pointers for queue type

Tags: c, pointers, queue

I am very new to c and pointers. Each time I thin k I have understood it, there comes a problem that I don't really understand (I spent some time reading c docs but pointers still remain unclear to me) :

```
typedef struct {
        int q[QUEUESIZE+1];
        int first;
        int last;
        int count;
} queue;

enqueue(queue *q, int x)
{
  if (q->count >= QUEUESIZE)
        printf("Warning: queue overflow enqueue x=%d\n",x);

  else {
    q->last = (q->last+1) % QUEUESIZE;
    q->q[ q->last ] = x;
    q->count = q->count + 1;
  } 
}
```

I hope my question will not be too opaque but could someone explain the use of pointer in enqueue function? I thought the principle of queuing was to allocate some precise successive  memory addresses, but it is not that for sure....

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get errors? What's not working? Please be precise, so you save us time about guessing :)

Comment: @m0skit0: Let me highlight it for you: ***could someone explain the use of pointer in `enqueue` function?***

Comment: @AlokSave Explain what? How a pointer works? I don't understand what he wants to know exactly...

Comment: @m0skit0 The code is indeed working (used to traverse graphs), but I don't understand what could be the advantages for passing a pointer as a variable and not a simple variable (enqueue(queue q, int x)) ?

Comment: @AlokSave, I don't understand the advantage to use pointer in those kind of functions (used to parse and traverse graphs). Is that a way to simulate a stack and to allocate values to successive memory addresses ?

Comment: Regarding the *Queue Pattern* you might like to read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29. A queues elements do not necessarily need to be placed in memory exactly the same way as their logical order is.

Comment: 1) you don't need the `last` element, only first+count. 2) using unsigned types for sizes, counts, and indexes is preferable (you do not want a negative index or size)

Comment: The last element of `q` is never used is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enqueue` takes a *queue* queue (queue of type *queue*) and add an element in it (which is made of an integer.

`queue *q` is a pointer, since, probably

- there could be more than one queue, and the parameter tells what queue we're talking about
- in order to avoid a global variable, the queue is given as parameter - we want a reference to the queue so that it can be modified, and the modification will stay live even after exiting `enqueue`

Passing a queue by value, as

```
enqueue(queue q, int x) { ...
```

would mean

- a lot of data given as parameter (copy of the queue myqueue to the `q` parameter)
- when `q` is modified, the modification is made on `q` within the `enqueue` function.
  The initially provided queue (myqueue) as parameter would not be modified

For instance

```
enqueue(queue q, int x) { 
  q.count++; // only the local q.count is changed, not myqueue.count
  // ...
}

// ...

queue myqueue;
// ...
enqueue (myqueue, 3); // enqueue changes its local parameter, myqueue is not affected
```

Besides, the `enqueue` function implementation could be optimized... (see *wildplasser* answer below who suggests a better *queue* implementation)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct queue {
        unsigned first;
        unsigned count;
        int q[QUEUESIZE];
        };

int enqueue(struct queue *q, int x)
{
  if (q->count >= QUEUESIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: queue overflow enqueue x=%d\n", x);
        return -1;
        }

  q->q[ (q->first+q->count++) % QUEUESIZE ] = x;
  return 0; /* success */ 
}
```

---

A few points:

- diagnostic output should go to stderr
- Using unsigned types for counts and offsets will (in most cases) avoid numerical underflow (or will transform it into overflow, which will fail faster ;-)
- you don't need three elements {head, tail, count}, only two {head, count} will suffice
- fewer variables := fewer assignments := fewer lines = less chance for error.
- The QUEUESIZE in the range check and modulo division should probably be replaced by `sizeof q->q / sizeof q->q[0]`, which is more robust.